# Kivy: Can the insert_text() function of TextInput be overrided in kv language?

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way to override the `insert_text()` function of `TextInput` only using kv language? I would like to restrict the text to numeric values only. I know there is a way to do it through python code, such as the following example I found:

```
class NumericInput(TextInput):

def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
    if not from_undo:
        try:
            int(substring)
        except ValueError:
            return
    super(NumericInput, self).insert_text(substring, from_undo)
```

But is there a way to do the same to the TextInput widget inside of the kv file:

```
    <Temperature>:
        name: "Temperature"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: "Farenheit"
            TextInput:
                id: user_input
                font_size: 50
                size_hint_y: None
                insert_text:
```

If not, how could I integrate the python code so that it restricts the input text of my `TextInput` widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override the method from kv language. If you want to do that, just override the method of your `Temperature` widget in its python definition.

TextInput also has an `input_filter` property that can be set to `'int'` or `'float'` to accept only numbers. You can set this in kv.